# How to assign ROW_NUMBER() to column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `UCP` , `TerritoriesInfo`

`UCP` have `TerritoriesID` , `Territories`

`TerritoriesInfo` have `ID` , `TerritoriesName`

I want to update `TerritoriesID` with Row_Number()

for example

UCP

```
TerritoriesID            Territories
1                          NULL
2                          NULL
3                          NULL
4                          NULL
5                          NULL
6                          NULL
7                          NULL
```

TerritoriesInfo

```
ID                 TerritoriesName
1                          A
2                          B
3                          C
4                          D
5                          ES
6                          T
7                          R
```

First i want to assign UCP.TerritoriesID = ROW_NUMBERS() second i want to Update UCP.Territories from TerritoriesInfo.TerritoriesName where UCP.TerritoriesID = TerritoriesInfo.ID
I tried Auto increment but it doesn't work when i use delete statement and try again
then i tried this query but doesn't work

```
update UCP SET TerritoriesID = ROW_NUMBER()
```

Comment: Use ROWNUM instead of ROW_NUMBER() - update UCP SET TerritoriesID = ROW_NUM;

Comment: 'ROW_NUM' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @JimMacaulay: this question is about (Microsoft) **SQL Server** - not Oracle .....

Comment: couldn't be done in sql ?

Comment: Your requirements aren't very clear - it's not clear to me how `ROW_NUMBER` enters into this. Are you trying to replace the contents of `UCP` with the contents of `TerritoriesInfo`, or does the real `UCP` have more columns that you're showing here?

Comment: i'm sorry for that .. two things .. first  i want to assign UCP.TerritoriesID = ROW_NUMBERS() second i want to Update UCP.Territories   from TerritoriesInfo.TerritoriesName where UCP.TerritoriesID = TerritoriesInfo.ID

Comment: i edited the question to be more clearly

Comment: What ordering should be used to assign `ROW_NUMBER` to `UCP.TerritoriesID`? Should it be based on the current value of `UCP.TerritoriesID`? (this is confusing, because in the example data, `UCP.TerritoriesID` already has these values).

Comment: I still can't understand the question.

Comment: Can you please clearly tell the problem at hand.

Comment: @EdHarper Should it be based on specific ordering ? i want to set row 1 = 1 row 2 = 2 and the same for the end of data column .. UCP.TerritoriesID in my case is empty but i give this example as the output i want .. i want to assign row number for each one

Comment: Yes, `ROW_NUMBER` requires `ORDER BY` - see my answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled  very simply i want to assign row number to column called UCP.TerritoriesID can i do that ?

Comment: @roshanmathew very simply i want to assign row number to column called UCP.TerritoriesID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `UCP.TerritoriesID` and  `TerritoriesInfo.ID` contain one-based sequences without gaps in the sample data, it's unclear what the requirement is here. My best guess is that the real `UCP.TerritoriesID` data is either non-sequential or doesn't start at one.

[`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) requires an `ORDER BY` in its `OVER` clause. I'm guessing that the row numbers should be assigned based on the current value of `UCP.TerritoriesID`, pending more information:

```
;WITH numCTE
AS
(   SELECT TerritoriesID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TerritoriesID) AS rn
    FROM UCP
)
UPDATE numCTE
SET TerritoriesID = rn
```

(I'm assuming that once you have this, you can handle the update of `UCP.Territories`)

Comment: Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Comment: i want to fill TerritoriesID form ucp with row_number() to handle other issues